# File appending problem with users input with strings... C++

Tags: c++, io, append, fstream

I am using user input to store strings in a txt file! However I have a problem. While inputting the users string for file writing is fine, I want to add new lines, but when a user inputs a phrase for the file, it writes the input to the file, but not in one complete line, for each word it takes one line...

Code :

```
        int Char;

        std::string Input;

        std::ofstream ofDocument;
        std::ifstream ifDocument;

        ifDocument.open("Path\\Document.txt");
        ofDocument.open("Path\\Document.txt", std::fstream::app); //I tried ios::app but same result...

        if (ifDocument)
        {
                while (1)
                {
                    std::cin >> Input;

                    ofDocument << Input << std::endl;

                    switch (Char = _getch())
                    {
                        case '@':

                        std::cout << "You pressed '@', exiting application..." << "\n" << std::endl;

                        exit(0);
                    }
                }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Cannot create 'Document.txt'. Please retry..." << std::endl;

            ThisFunction();
        }
```

Exemple : User Input : 1st line : Hello i am writing in a text file

2nd line : Will this work?

Output in file :
Hello : new line
i : new line
am : new line
writing : new line
in : new line
a : new line
text : new line
file : new line
Will : new line
this : new line
work?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You should not open the same file more than once.

Comment: Alright... i just want to make sure to avoid errors as much as possible but i can see that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try putting getline(std::cin, Input) below std::cin >> Input to capture all spaces so that it won't be a one line in every word. Hope this works

Comment: this works but for some reason getline craps itself and doesnt display the first char of the sentence, thanks tho!